# .NET application fails after Windows Update KB4457034

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update, .net

Just installed the following Windows Update:

[Security and Quality Rollup for .NET Framework 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, and 4.7.2 for Windows 8.1, RT 8.1 and Server 2012 R2 (KB 4457034)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4457034/description-of-the-security-and-quality-rollup-for-net-framework-4-6-4)

as part of the bigger KB4457920 update.

However, after installing it, many .NET application that are running on the server start failing in different moments. When the applications fail, the following errors are logged in the Event Viewer and uninstalling the update is the only solution.

Every time the applications fail, these 3 errors are logged at the same time:

**Error 1:**

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException
(different sub-stack traces)
```

**Error 2:**

```
Faulting application name: ABC.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5bf5574b
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.19178, time stamp: 0x5bc006fd
Exception code: 0xc0000006
Fault offset: 0x0000000000008e6c
Faulting process id: 0x868
Faulting application start time: 0x01d483667e54d612
Faulting application path: D:\Hosting\ABC.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 5da6c6cc-ef5a-11e8-8125-0ab333379659
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

**Error 3:**

```
Windows cannot access the file  for one of the following reasons: there is a problem with the network connection, the disk that the file is stored on, or the storage drivers installed on this computer; or the disk is missing. Windows closed the program ABC because of this error.

Program: ABC
File: 

The error value is listed in the Additional Data section.
User Action
1. Open the file again. This situation might be a temporary problem that corrects itself when the program runs again.
2. If the file still cannot be accessed and
    - It is on the network, your network administrator should verify that there is not a problem with the network and that the server can be contacted.
    - It is on a removable disk, for example, a floppy disk or CD-ROM, verify that the disk is fully inserted into the computer.
3. Check and repair the file system by running CHKDSK. To run CHKDSK, click Start, click Run, type CMD, and then click OK. At the command prompt, type CHKDSK /F, and then press ENTER.
4. If the problem persists, restore the file from a backup copy.
5. Determine whether other files on the same disk can be opened. If not, the disk might be damaged. If it is a hard disk, contact your administrator or computer hardware vendor for further assistance.

Additional Data
Error value: C000026E
Disk type: 0
```

Note that the last error is as-is, there are 2 spaces where the file name should be specified: *"...cannot access the file (blank path) for one of the..."*.

Since it's an update to prevent "remote code execution" it needs to be installed. Is there any re-configuration and/or code changes needed after the installation to prevent the issue?

Windows version: Window Server 2012 R2 Version 6.3.9600  --  .NET Version: 4.5.x

**Note:** I've installed all the pending updates and this happened:

- Installed Nov-2018 updates (KB4467242) successfully. KB4457920 failed. > Apps started failing.
- Reinstalled KB4457920 and it was failing. Uninstalling KB4457034 fixed the issue.

Comment: Is D: a network share?  Or is there anything else unusual about it?  See, e.g., [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20050572/886887).

Comment: No, it's not. It's a local disk on an EC2 instance on AWS. The apps fail, for example when sending an email so it might be connecting somewhere, but it's a webserver and has no connectivity issue afaik

Comment: Hmmm.  If there was a general problem with the September .NET updates I'd expect there to have been reports of it before now.  It might be specific to Amazon, do you have a support contract?  Have you confirmed that removing the update resolves the problem?  Have you tried installing the November update (KB4467241) instead or as well as the September update?

Comment: Incidentally, you're asking about KB4457034 which applies to .NET 4.6 and later, but you say your .NET version is 4.5?

Comment: True. I might be wrong about .NET version then (that's what a developer said). I've installed it and uninstalled it twice and that was the update with issues. All other updates are installed. Actually I've added important info, because that update failed installing the first time (maybe a part of it) and had to re-install it.

Comment: Your app developers should investigate this as a possible (very serious) bug in the application.

Comment: In theory, if you have KB4467242 installed then you shouldn't need KB4457920 because the updates are cumulative. The update replacement information in the articles doesn't confirm this, but I suspect this is just a documentation error, there seems to be some confusion caused by MS deciding to turn pre-release updates into release updates without changing the KB number. You should be able to confirm this by looking at the KB article for the update you're having trouble with, checking the list of file versions, and confirming that the files on your server are the same or newer even without it.

Comment: ... you're the second person I've seen reporting an issue caused by a superseded .NET update, even though the presence of superseded updates should make absolutely no difference.  I'm wondering if there's something wrong with the .NET servicing stack.